# Android: PhoneStateListener not working in Service

Tags: android, service, phone-state-listener

I'm trying to build an application that logs when I accept and reject calls. Therefor I'm using a PhoneStateListener.

When I start the listener in the `onCreate()` method it is stopping its activity after some time. As far as I know Android closes the App because it has no focus.

I tried to work around that behavior with starting a service. All the code I wrote works fine and doesn't get killed by android...but the PhoneStateListener doesn't recieve any events.

How I start the Service:

```
public class RunningService extends IntentService {

    /**
     * A constructor is required, and must call the super IntentService(String)
     * constructor with a name for the worker thread.
     */
    public RunningService() {
        super("RunningService");
    }

    /**
     * The IntentService calls this method from the default worker thread with
     * the intent that started the service. When this method returns,
     * IntentService stops the service, as appropriate.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        //...some code...creating a notification
        startForeground(12345, notification);

        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) this
                .getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        telephonyManager.listen(new PhoneStateListenerImpl(),
                PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

        while (true) {
            ...some code to do...until Exit is called by user
        }
    }
}
```

The PhoneStateListener with basic output:

```
public class PhoneStateListenerImpl extends PhoneStateListener {

    public PhoneStateListenerImpl() {
        super();
        Log.v("psListener", "constructor");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

        switch (state) {
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
            Log.v("PhoneStateListener", "IDLE");
            break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
            Log.v("PhoneStateListener", "OFFHOOK");
            break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
            Log.v("State", "Ringing");
            break;
        default: {
            Log.v("Status", "something");
        }
        }
    }
}
```

I get the Log output frome the Listeners constructor, but whenever something changes (like I'm calling someone) nothing happens.

The same Listener started from `onCreate()` works fine.

Maybe I'm missing something

I just tried:
I tried to ask the TelephonyManager for the phone state in the while loop of the Service. This works fine. But I guess this is just a dirty workaround.

Has anybody an idea what could be the problem?

Comment: I don't use an IntentService. I create a class extending service and register the listener in the onStartCommand method. That works fine.

Comment: In the oncreate solved the problem! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you are registering your PhoneStateListener on onHandleIntent instead of that register your listener in onStartCommand or onCreate functions, and make sure you have mentioned following permissions in your project's manifest